# Magento 2 Admin Action Logging Custom/Magento Module in M2 Community Version

Tags: magento2

I am creating a multiple stores website and there are many staff user So I want to track changes history.

How to track product information which update user staff in Magento and I want to revert if the wrong update.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 provides admin / sub admin action logging feature in enterprise version.

Go to -> Admin -> STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Admin > Admin Actions Logging. So you can track changes but you have to revert changes manually one by one.

You can use some extensions to use this feature in community version:

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageaurigait-adminlogger.html

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-admin-action-log-extension.html

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html

Comment: there is other to way for  logging without purchase